# Node.js application still works after deleting the source files

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching

I have a Node.js application which can work even if I completely remove its source files from the computer.

How is it possible?

I heard a little bit about that Node.js app is automatically caching source files to work more efficiently.

Does it mean that these files are still existing somewhere?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Is the node app currently running when you delete the source? Or do you delete and then successfully start the app?

Comment: node.js doesn't cache source files. It interprets them as soon as they are required/imported. Scripts don't get interpreted multiple times in a typical node application. Even if you `require` the same JS file twice, it will only be executed once.

Comment: Presumably you're referring to being able to delete the source files whilst the app is running? That's because Node uses JIT compiling, the JS is compiled and loaded into mem so the files aren't locked or being "used" during execution....try restsrting your app, you'll find there's no hidden caching going on :)

Comment: FYI, this is no different than once you run a .exe application on windows and then delete the .exe, the app continues to run.  It's because the code has already been loaded into memory.  So deleting the file doesn't affect the running application.

Comment: You can even `function a() { require('./something').a = 5; }` and `function b() { console.log(require('./something')); } // {a:5}`  to use any require as a localStorage of sorts (until your app ends).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite JavaScript being an interpreted language, node.js compiles your source files into native machine code. Once you start an application, you can delete the JavaScript files and it'll continue to run as the code has already been compiled.

Here's an excerpt from Wikipedia regarding node's v8 engine that may help you better understand what's going on:

> V8 compiles JavaScript to native machine code (IA-32, x86-64, ARM,
>   PowerPC, IBM s390 or MIPS ISAs) before executing it, instead of more
>   traditional techniques such as interpreting bytecode or compiling the
>   whole program to machine code and executing  it from a filesystem. The
>   compiled code is additionally optimized (and  re-optimized)
>   dynamically at runtime, based on heuristics of the code's  execution
>   profile. Optimization techniques used include inlining, elision of
>   expensive runtime properties, and inline caching, among many others.

---

As stated by David784:

> Might be worth noting that this compiling happens on an as-needed
>   basis. For example, if you have a single require('./other.js') inside
>   of a callback, other.js won't be interpreted/compiled until that
>   callback is called.

So your application may work once deleted for specific operations, but once a new dependency is used, node won't be able to find your application files and will inevitably crash.

Comment: Might be worth noting that this compiling happens on an as-needed basis. For example, if you have a single `require('./other.js')` inside of a callback, `other.js` won't be interpreted/compiled until that callback is called.

Comment: @David784 Great point. Added that information to the main answer for visibility.